# Can't resolve Amazon analytics host

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, analytics, amazon-cognito

Amazon analytics in my android app is trying to connect to this host *"mobileanalytics.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"* , but it is unable to resolve it, resulting in this error:

> I/AmazonHttpClient: Unable to execute HTTP request: Unable to resolve
>   host "mobileanalytics.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated
>   with hostname 10-12 14:05:34.870 8709-8975/lv.app.android.debug
>   I/AmazonHttpClient: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve
>   host "mobileanalytics.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated
>   with hostname

Is this domain correct? I have tried from my local wired connection and mobile internet.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to call AWS Mobile Analytics in the eu-west-1 region, but Mobile Analytics is only available in the us-east-1 region. Make sure you specify us-east-1 when you create the client, so it targets the correct endpoint.